# Add top level JSON to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

does anyone know how to append a top level json to an existing object?

this is what I have:

```
   var url = "http://domain.com/gettxt";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                rootData = data;
                renderView();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error" + errorThrown)
            }
        });
```

At this point, data contains the following:

```
   [{"id":1,"title":"Johnson"}]
```

And I need it to be like this:

```
   { "record": [ {"id":1}, {"title":"Johnson"} ] }
```

In other words:

```
   rootData = "{ "record":" + data + "}";
```

Does anyone know how can I do the above? Unfortunately adding the top level before it comes to Javascript is not an option, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly add object type like this,

```
rootData = { record: data };
```

Your final code will be

```
var url = "http://domain.com/gettxt";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            rootData = { record: data };
            renderView();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error" + errorThrown)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use an object literal to do this:

```
rootData = { record: data };
```

So your code would look like this:

```
 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     rootData = { record: data };
     renderView();
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var arr = [{"id":1,"title":"Johnson"}];
var obj ={};
obj.record = arr;
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [{"id":1,"title":"Johnson"}]
root = {record: a}
```